# Developing applications under Cyanogenmod? How compatible to vanila Android? (Nexus devices)

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-4, performance, nexus-5, vanilla-android

If I am to develop (and test) my application under Cyanongenmod (base install, without any additional changes), how confident can I be that I would see similar performance of my application on the vanilla Android version? In particular I am interested in the base/hardware performance that is not so much affected by changes to GUI, animation or depends so much on user interactions.

Is the default frequency governor on Cyanongenmod (OnDemand) is the same as default frequency governor on vanilla Android?

What other things could affect performance on Cyanogenmod versus vanilla/stock Android?

** I am using Nexus 4 and Nexus 5 devices.

Answer (score 0):

The governor is dependent on the OEM's choice. For example, some choose mpdecision, others use ondemand or interactive. Still others use conservative. That being said, many of them are implemented differently (ie conservative mode on a Samsung may differ wildly from conservative on an HTC). Cyanogenmod though is just based on AOSP code so ondemand/interactive governor performance under Cyanogenmod should be comparable to the stock governors for that device (OEM's implementation).  This is assuming that the Cyanogenmod branch for said device has proper hardware acceleration and what not. As Cyanogenmod is built from AOSP code, this is not a given.

TLDR: I have had a lot of phones with Cyanogenmod. It feels snappier and is lightweight but for the heavy duty apps or games, I notice very little (if any) difference in performance.